# Can not set Upstream path to service in Kong Db-less mode

Tags: kong

I am using Kong in Db-less mode. I first used the yaml config file to configure services, as defined in the [doc](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.4.x/db-less-and-declarative-config/), like this:

```
_format_version: "2.1"
_transform: true


services:
  - name: controllers
    url: https://10.5.131.142:3002
    routes:
    - name: controller-routes
      paths:
      - /admin/controllers 

  - name: vpnprofiles
    url: https://10.5.131.142:3002
    routes:
    - name: vpnprofiles-routes
      paths:
      - /admin/vpnprofiles

  - name: device_report
    url: https://10.5.131.142:3000
    routes:
    - name: device-report-routes
      paths:
      - /reporting/device_report
```

However, this does not set the path used for requests to the upstream service. When looking at the field, it is returned as null.
I tried reseting the config using /config endpoint, but the field "path" is not taken into consideration. It is not rejected, but it does not update the field though.

Is there a way of setting the path to the upstream service ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that I have to set it directly on the url field, there is no path field in the kong yaml config file.